# (Spoiler) Valiant Hearts, did Emile know about Karl?

Tags: valiant-hearts

Alright, the title is spoiler free and shows a bit what I'm on about.

Now the actual question, which contains major spoilers (Really, if you haven't played the game yet, close this page now and go do so):

> When Emile died, did he know Karl was still alive? He thought Karl got killed at the POW camp. As far as I know Emile never got to know Karl was still alive. Maybe I just missed something in the story though. It would be pretty sad if Emile did die with the thought of Karl being dead...

It seems like this is the first question about this game on this site, which is a shame. It really is a masterpiece.

Comment: There really isn't too much need to ask any questions about this game. It's fairly straight forward (in regards to your 'first question' comment).

Comment: @deutschZuid I have to agree on that, but I'm amazed by the simple things people will still have questions about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to think so, if you listen to his last words he says that he let Karl down, but that his sacrifice was not in vain because blah blah blah honor or something (too lazy to write it all you get the point). So he thinks that Karl is still dead which is really just insanely depressing, but that's such a central theme of the game that war is loss